# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when trying to get wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm facing some issue and I have no idea how to solve it. 
I'm publishing jax-ws service, and when I want to access to created wsdl file I'm getting this error:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - /ws?wsdl: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/io/AbstractConnection
```

My code for creating and publishing service:

```
SOAPHandlerImpl handlerImpl = new SOAPHandlerImpl();
JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
svrFactory.setServiceClass(SOAPHandler.class);
svrFactory.setAddress("http://localhost:81/ws");
svrFactory.setServiceBean(handlerImpl);
svrFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
svrFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
svrFactory.create();
System.out.println("Service created");
```

I found some solutions, I have added `jetty-util` to my classpath but it didn't fixed issue.
Anyone have some idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I had to add `jetty-io` to classpath.